# Animation of 2D plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, line

I have a setup that measures the temperature profile of a piece of equipment at an interval using 11 probes and I wish to make an animated plot for how the profile evolves. I have my temperature data in a simple m-by-n matrix (about 11x50000) where each column represents a probe and each row represents a new set of measurements. It is to be plotted against a simple 0:1:10 vector to see how a temperature bulge moves over time.

Is this even possible in Matlab and if so how? I have been browsing around for quite a bit without finding anything useful. Sorry if there are any existing posts I haven't stumbled upon.

Edit: Image added for illustration. The plots in the image are plots of individual rows from the matrix i wish to animate. The example plots are about 2 minutes apart in the measurements. What I seek is to have a single animated figure that shows how the temperature bulge grows and shifts along the y-axis. Equally important, I wish to export this animated figure for use in a presentation.

[image: example]

vars in matlab

[image: variables]

Comment: A part from the _animation_ do you want to plot 11 lines in a single figure?

Comment: It's ust one line that should update. Just a simple animation that shows how the graph evolves over time. It should look like a simple xy plot with a bulge moving upwards

Comment: The best why to try and describe it would be frame one: ^____ frame two: __ ^___ frame three: ____^_ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understand yor question, you might try the following:
**(further modified the code following the last comment)**

```
% Generate example data
data=randi(10,1,100);
data=[data;randi(10,1,100)+10]
data=[data;randi(10,1,100)+20]
data=[data;randi(10,1,100)+30]
data=[data;randi(10,1,100)+40]
t=1:101;

h_fig=figure
axes
plot(data(:,1),t(1))
grid on
xlim([0 100])
% legend(the_legend)
hold on
for i=1:100-1
   tmp_h=plot(data(i,:),[1:5],'-d')
   M(i)=getframe(h_fig);
   pause(.3)
   delete(tmp_h)
end
movie2avi(M,'testMovie2______.avi','fps',3)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I think I might not have explained myself well enough. It is a single graph i want that is updated each frame such that frame 1 is data(:,1) plotted, frame two is data(:,2) etc.

Comment: I do not follow you: at the second iteration, for example, do you want to delete the plot of `data(:,1)` and plot `data(:,2)`? If so your plot will look like a sequence of `markers` moving `up` and `down`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for although I would like the markers to be connected by a line.

Comment: I've added some code in the answer to open a new figure and plot in it nevertheless, I still can not understand what do you want to plot. Can you add a picture showiing it?

Comment: Added an image and some more text to the original post. Each of the plots are about 200 rows apart. I want an animated plot that includes all the rows.

Comment: That's perfect. Is it possible to save this to a file somehow for playback outside Matlab?

Comment: I've updated the code, now it generates an `.avi` movie.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with fitting it to my data. My y axis is a 1x11 double and x axis 25000x11 double
how do fit the code for that? (added the top bit of my data in the original post to give an idea.

Comment: Code updated; I this answer your question you might "accept" the answer. I've got the "warning" _Please avoid extended discussions in comments_; unfortunately, the OP has not enough reputations to chat. Hope this will be my last comment.

Comment: thank you for all the help and sorry for the trouble! Waiting for your code update :)

Comment: Code updated: see `data=data` and `tmp_h=plot(data(i,:),[1:5],'-d')`